# Finding continuous functions from a set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $A=\{0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\}$. I want to find continuous functions from $f:A\to \mathbb R$.

I proceed in this way. Any sequence converges to $x(\neq 0)$ will be eventually constant sequences, and so any function will be continuous at $x$. But what about $0$? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Any function continuous at 0  and defined on $A$ will  be continuous on $A$.